# MKOverlay doesn't render a second time on iOS7

Tags: ios7, mkannotation, mkoverlay

I have a map view that has annotations on it. With each annotation, I need to show an overlay that is just a circle. This circle needs to be one of two different colours depending on a value. The user can select something else on the screen, and all annotations and overlays need to be removed, and new ones need to be added based on the newly selected item.

The first time I load the controller having the map view, everything works great. When the user selects a new item, the old annotations and overlays are removed, and the new annotations and overlays are added, but the overlays don't appear. When I put breakpoints in, I don't see the mapview:rendererForOverlay method getting called after a user has selected a new item. Below is the code I am using:

In viewDidLoad, I have the following:

```c
_mapview.delegate = self;
[self placePinsOnMap];
```

The placePinsOnMap: method has the following:

```c
- (void)placePinsOnMap {
    AMapAnnotation* annotation;

    for (APlace* place in _selectedItem.places) {
        annotation = [[AMapAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:place.name subtitle:place.subtitle coordinate:place.location];
        annotation.object = place;

        [_mapview addAnnotation:annotation];
        [_mapview addOverlay:[[AMapOverlay alloc] initWithCenterCoordinate:place.location radius:[_place.size floatValue]*1000 object:place] level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];
    }
}
```

Each time an overlay is added, the mapview:rendererForOverlay is called. This looks like this:

```c
- (MKOverlayRenderer*)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {
    MKCircleRenderer* circleRenderer;
    AMapOverlay* mapOverlay;
    APlace* place;

    mapOverlay = (AMapOverlay*)overlay;
    place = mapOverlay.object;

    circleRenderer = [[MKCircleRenderer alloc] initWithCircle:mapOverlay];
    if ([place.radius floatValue] >= 5 && [place.radius floatValue] <= 10) {
        circleRenderer.fillColor = [[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
    } else {
        circleRenderer.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
    }

    return circleRenderer;
}
```

When a user selects a new item, I remove all annotations and overlays, and I place the new annotations and their overlays for the new item selected:

```c
- (void)onScrollviewTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    CGPoint point;

    point = [recognizer locationInView:_scrollview];

    for (ACard* card in _cards) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(card.frame, point)) {
            card.selected = YES;
            _selectedItem = card.item;
            NSArray* array = [_mapview annotations];
            for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in array) {
                if (annotation != _userAnnotation) {
                    [_mapview removeAnnotation:annotation];
                }
            }

            [_mapview removeOverlays:[_mapview overlays]];
            [self placePinsOnMap];
        } else {
             card.selected = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

The AMapOverlay class is a subclass of MKCircle and simply holds the coordinate, a radius value and a place object which is used to determine what colour the overlay should be. I have the boundingMapRect overridden in the AMapOverlay class:

```c
- (MKMapRect)boundingMapRect {
    MKMapPoint upperLeft = MKMapPointForCoordinate(self.coordinate);
    MKMapRect bounds = MKMapRectMake(upperLeft.x, upperLeft.y, self.radius*2, self.radius*2);
    return bounds;
}
```

Just to reiterate what my problem is: The first time I load the controller having the map view, everything works great. I see the annotations along with their overlays. When the user selects a new item, the old annotations and overlays are removed, and the new annotations are added along with the overlays, but the overlays don't appear.

Does anyone have any ideas why this would be?

Comment: Is the radius correct when a new item is selected?  Is the map view's delegate still set (the standard red pins don't need a viewForAnnotation but overlays must implement the delegate method and therefore delegate must be set)?  Are the center coordinates of the new overlays correct?  I'm not sure you need to override boundingMapRect and I think MKCircle sets the "upper left" to the real upper left corner of a square _centered_ on coordinate.

Comment: Not directly related and not the "cause" of the problem:  The line where you call addOverlay should be broken up into multiple lines.  Writing that code as one line does not make it faster.  It just makes it very difficult to read and (most importantly) to debug.  Break it up into multiple lines so you can step through the individual calculations (eg. radius) and check the intermediate values.

Comment: Thanks for the response Anna. I can confirm that I have verified everything you mentioned, the coordinate is set, and correctly so in the coordinates that it should hold, and the radius is also correct. The delegate is set on the mapview to which the annotations and overlays are being added. Can you clarify what you meant by "...but overlays must implement the delegate method and therefore delegate must be set". I don't know overlays to take delegates. In fact, there's no delegate property on overlays.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that to show overlays, you must implement rendererForOverlay or viewForOverlay and be sure that the map view's delegate property is set.  If you don't implement one of those methods or the map view's delegate is not set, the map view will not display a "default" overlay view.  However, for annotations if you don't implement viewForAnnotation or the map view's delegate is not set, the map view _will_ display a default red pin for you.

Comment: Aside from the obvious, are you perhaps calling the addOverlay in a background thread?  Try to come up with a small, self-contained example that duplicates the problem (I assume the full code is too much to post).

Comment: The code I put up is as small as I could get to reproduce the problem. I have all the relevant delegate methods, rendererForOverlay, viewForAnnotation, etc. Everything works fine on the first run. The problem only comes up when I remove an overlay and try and add new ones. When I do this, the rendererForOverlay isn't called. Seems like the problem only occurs if I call removeOverlays: or removeOverlay on the map view. Could there be a bug in MKMapView perhaps?

Comment: Oh, and no, I am not calling it on a background thread. Everything is happing on the main thread.